# ngrams (tweak to existing bash script)

Tags: bash

A thoughtful and intelligent person helped me out a while back with a bash script, but I recently realized I didn't explain what I wanted clearly enough. I have a long list of phrases (ngrams) in a plain text file. If one phrase is a fragment of another, only the longer one is of any use, so the shorter one needs to be deleted. The code below deletes the longer one. I hope switching that will be a matter of changing a few characters.

```
#! /bin/bash
((n=${1:-0})) || exit 1

declare -A ngrams

while read -ra line; do
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#line[@]}; i++)); do
            ((ngrams[${line[@]:i:n}]++))
    done
done 

for i in "${!ngrams[@]}"; do
    printf '%d\t%s\n' "${ngrams[$i]}" "$i"
done
```

Comment: So maybe he wasn't that `thoughtful` after all (given that he didn't explain it clearly so as to enable *you* **understand**).

Comment: @user1889034 - Can you provide an example of the input data?  Can any of the undesired fragments appear in the middle of the more desired longer fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by changing a few characters, but newly written:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a ngrams
mapfile -t ngrams < $1
for ((i=0; i<${#ngrams[@]}; i++)); do
    for ((j=0; j<${#ngrams[@]}; j++)); do
        if  ((  i!=j )) && [[  "${ngrams[j]}" == *"${ngrams[i]}"* ]]; then
            continue 2
        fi
    done
    echo ${ngrams[i]} >> $2
done
```

You may call it by `ngram.sh <infile> <outfile>`. E.g.:

```
> cat txt.in
foo
me me me
kaaz
bar
foo bar
blub
me
> ./ngram.sh txt.in txt.out
> cat txt.out
me me me
kaaz
foo bar
blub
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks so much!